# Dürr vs. trocken

Tags: difference, word-choice

Dictionaries show both as "dry, arid" etc., wiktionary shows them as synonyms. I asked in a chat, and got replies about liquids on the outside or inside, which confused me even further.

What's the difference between the two, if any? Are they interchangeable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***trocken:*** dry or arid, used for **objects, weather and land**.
also: metaphorical *dry* as in dry wit or dry wine
noun: ***Trockenheit*** - *dryness*
comparative always means *drier*

***dürr:*** dry or arid, used for **land and soil**, usually not single objects
also: *very thin* (plants or also persons), dried out (*verdorrt*)
noun: ***Dürre*** - *drought*
comparative means *thinner*

Comment: For the meaning of ‘thin’ for _dürr_ also see [my answer to another question](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/30959/what-is-the-difference-between-dünn-schlank-and-mager)

Comment: @Crissov thanks for the addendum. I won't expand on that here, because this question focused more on the *dry*-aspect.

Answer (score 2):

"Dürr" is used more regarding vegetation and agriculture. I would say ...

"Eine große Dürre kam über das Land." "A great drought came upon the land."

Means: There was no rain and so they had problems to grow food.

If you're not sure then use rather "trocken". Makes more sense in most cases and is more general.